# Why is Facebook not showing in Shotwell photo manager?

Tags: shotwell, facebook

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and have been organising my photographs with Shotwell photo manager. A lot of websites say I should be able to publish/share my photos on Facebook through Shotwell but when I go to do so (or look in the plugins menu), FB is not there.
Is there no support for FB in shotwell anymore or is this a bug?

What do I do?

Edit: I have tried going through the Yorba PPA but that seems to not work now.

Answer (score 0):

We, the community, need to implement a new way of uploading to FB via Shotwell as the old API [is not supported anymore](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/shotwell/-/issues/32).

> Facebook support is broken since August 1st, 2018. The API Shotwell used was replaced by something completely different. There is no replacement for Shotwell for now.

The new API, Graph, has to be used, e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/?locale=de_DE